# API response format for date+time (iso thing?)

Tags: php, api, date, format, iso

What's the standard (or some kind of iso-conform thing) format to display date (year, month, day) and time (Hours minutes and seconds) together as an result of an API Request? Or should a timestamp be returned in this case?

Comment: Unix Timestamp; the number of seconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00-00:00` (UTC).  You should send the timestamp, but if you must send a formatted date, send the ISO8601, which looks like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)** format. And use **UTC** timezone always. Its the standard by ISO and should be parsable by any library.

Example `2012-02-28T20:27:21+0000`

In php use [DateTimeZone](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) and [DateTime](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object combindly to get an ISO8601 date.

```
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $dt->format(DATE_ISO8601)`
```

See [Date/Time](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) in PHP manual to know more.

Comment: Don't forget the timezone to avoid confusions.

Comment: @Michael-O Thanks. It should be UTC all the time. `Z` in ISO8601 means Zero zone. I added it.

Comment: That PHP code adds the compressed offset rather than normalized Zulu time.

Comment: @Michael-O Didn't get you (may be I am not a good English reader). I see this works, http://ideone.com/lhc0d

Comment: The `DATE_ISO8601` format pattern does not correspond to your example.

Comment: Care to explain minus voting?

Comment: You have changed the default timezone of the PHP env which might have implications the rest of the code.

Comment: @Michael-O Thanks a lot. I was in fact searching a way to change the date time zone. But wasn't successful. Later I found DateTimeZone object supports "UTC" string!

Answer (score 2):

I think returning `timestamp` would be a better idea.
It allows your API users to manipulate it easily.
(My opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Either do a integer unix timestamp or do full [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

Answer (score 0):

**RFC822 Format**: 18 Feb 2012 14:27:18 -0000

```
DAY MONTH YEAR HOUR:MINUTES:SECONDS UTC-OFFSET
```

Using [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
date('d M y H:i:s O')
```

Twitter's API uses it, And some of its benefits are that it's readable by humans and easy to parse in PHP, JavaScript, And other languages. And you know which timezone the date is presented in.

Comment: RFC822 is not a very good format, neither language-agnostic nor string-sortable. It's a pre-ISO relic.